# Private Kudu install, how to inject AppSettings like Azure Websites?

Tags: azure, appsettings, kudu

When using the Azure Websites with ASP.NET apps, it is possible to configure through the Azure portal a series of `AppSettings` to be injected at deployment time into the `web.config` behavior of the app. How can this be reproduced using a private instance of Kudu?

Answer (score 0):

## First question

Yes you can enter some AppSettings directely in the web site's portal.
You do this by going to the CONFIGURE tab and setting some keys/values into the APPSETTINGS section.

This is absolutely transparent for your application. You just read the appsetting with ConfigurationManager as if the setting were in the web.config file. The new value has precedence over the value in the web.config.

This is interesting if you have sensitive value to set.

An alternative (more interesting with web jobs) is to read your appsetting directely from an automatically created environment variable.
If you have a FOO key in the setting, you also get a environment variable named
APPSETTING_FOO

Recently the new portal give you the new possibility to set a appsettings key specific to the slot by just checking a checkbox:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/azure-machine-learning-service-hadoop-storm-cluster-scaling-linux-support-site-recovery-and-more